# Could putting a manuscript onto arXiv affect the probability of a journal accepting it (even if the journal explicitly allows pre-prints)?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, arxiv, peer-review

I am wondering if anyone knows, thinks or has measured whether putting a paper on arXiv before submitting to a journal has any impact on the paper reviewing process and on it being accepted or rejected?

I do know why to put it on arXiv. There are plenty of reasons for that and it has been discussed exhaustively here and elsewhere in academia. **This question is not about that**.

I know that journals have different policies about this. I read them, I checked them, I am fine there as well. **This question is not about that either**.

My question is whether, in practice, there is a known impact or can anyone speculate if publishing to arXiv has a positive or negative effect.
For instance, the editor/reviewers can see the paper in the arXiv and can have a different position about it; some people might have experiences relating to that from the point of view of reviewer/editor/submitter.

It would also be very interesting to see statistics showing whether the reviewing process for random sets of manuscript submissions with and without preprint versions differ, but I would guess those do not exist yet.

Comment: If you receive feedback on the preprint, and use it to improve the manuscript prior to journal submission, presumably there's a positive effect. But I haven't seen any related statistics.

Comment: I also wonder whether if an ArXiv paper has accumulated many cites, does it mean a journal will more likely accept it?  I.e., can a journal use ArXiV cites to select articles that have a clear evidence of impact?

Comment: Good points both. The improvements is a bit more indirect. But the point raised by @Prof.SantaClaus is a good one. If the preprint has cites it indicates it is interesting for the community and also it may impress the reviewers.

Comment: "Can anyone speculate"? Sure, they can and will, but I don't know of even any anecdotal evidence where this mattered.

The closest example I'm aware of is this story: https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/201211/preprint.cfm
but even here the issue was really that the authors put out a second preprint that, at first glance, appeared to undermine their initial result that was under peer review. So it's not really the same issue.

Comment: As a reviewer, I greatly prefer reviewing papers that have been posted to the arXiv, as anything interesting I learn won't be privileged information. I'd rather not invest time into reading something which I'm forbidden from discussing with others.

Comment: As a Reviewer, the first thing I do when reviewing is checking if the paper has been submitted elsewhere. If I see it online in arXiv I will still conduct my review (impartially), but I will notify the editors that there may be a violation of CoC because it may void the "double blind" peer review.

Answer (score 3):

I am an editor for two journals that allow arxiv preprints, and at those journals whether a manuscript is posted on arxiv has no influence on whether it is accepted.

Answer (score 2):

My speculation is that posting on arXiv has little or no impact on odds of acceptance.

When I review a paper, I'm looking for relevance, impact, and correctness. I understand editors are looking for the same. Whether a paper is already on arXiv or not simply doesn't affect any of that stuff.

I suppose if a preprint attracted a good number of citations, this could be a positive signal about the paper's potential impact. But in practice I wouldn't seek out this information as a reviewer, so I likely wouldn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no plausible mechanism by which a manuscript being posted on arXiv could affect that manuscript’s chance of getting accepted by a journal.

If you suspect otherwise, then you simply don’t understand how experienced researchers think about arXiv, and/or how much thought and care editors and reviewers put into doing their jobs in a professional manner.

This applies to disciplines where uploading preprints to arXiv is the norm. In other areas where public preprints are taboo or frowned upon, the answer could be different,

Comment: I can imagine ways how having a preprint on the arXiv slightly improves the chance.

Comment: @Arno I’d be happy to hear what they are. And, to be clear, I’m not referring to second order effects like the author getting useful feedback that helps them improve the paper prior to submitting it to a journal. My interpretation of the question is that it specifically asks us to ignore such effects.

Comment: A bit convoluted: If someone has already read the paper from the arXiv (and its good), they would be more willing to accept a referee request (as they already did part of the work). Thus, papers on the arXiv are slightly more likely to be refereed by authors from their core target audience, who will be more sympathetic and understand it better,

Comment: @Arno I see no reason why this effect would be statistically biased in favor of acceptance. It might mean the reviewers end up being marginally _more qualified_ to review the paper. Even that conclusion sounds a bit too speculative for me to think it’s worth entertaining seriously. In any case the many known, non-speculative reasons why putting your papers on arXiv is a good idea will easily drown out this tiny source of (biased, or not) statistical noise.

Answer (score 0):

> It would also be very interesting to see statistics showing whether the >reviewing process for random sets of manuscript submissions with and without preprint versions differ, but I would guess those do not exist yet.

I think that "statstics" may be misleading. There is no point oto average over different journals, and the "statistics" for each journal will be different. Also papers are not put on arxiv not by a "random" decision but based on specific reasoning.  If on average more papers that are on arxiv get published, does it mean the journal favours prior arxiv publication, or that there was some reason for nor putting paper on arxiv and this has lead to ultimate rejection?

That said I do not know a single case where there is a an "unofficial" policy of not allowing arxiv preprints. If it exists, it is official.